# How to pass index variable to html element in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to pass `index` variable to build html in append() function?

```
.directive('grid', ['$compile', function(compile) {
      return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
          elements: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          element.find('div.grid-cell').map(function(index, cell) {
            $(cell).append(
              '<div ng-repeat="el in elements">' +
              '<div ng-if="d.grid_id === index">{{index}} {{grid}}</div></div>'
            );
        }
      }
    }]);
```

Comment: use `$index` instead of `index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have no angular expirience but simple string concatination should do the trick :

```
        $(cell).append(
          '<div ng-repeat="el in elements">' +
          '<div ng-if="d.grid_id === '+index+'">{{grid}}</div></div>'
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use map function index then use.

```
$(cell).append(
    '<div ng-repeat="el in elements">' +
    '<div ng-if="d.grid_id === ' + index + '">{{grid}}</div></div>'
);
```

and if you want use ng-repeat index then use

```
$(cell).append(
    '<div ng-repeat="el in elements">' +
    '<div ng-if="d.grid_id === $index">{{grid}}</div></div>'
);
```